# how to read property name with spaces in java

Tags: java, properties

I am trying to load all the property names present in the properties file using the below code:

```
for(Enumeration<String> en = (Enumeration<String>) prop.propertyNames();en.hasMoreElements();){

    String key = (String)en.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Property name is "+key);
}
```

But my properties file has the below contents:

```
username=
password=
Parent file name=
Child file name =
```

After running the code I am getting output as :

```
username password Parent Child
```

If the property name has spaces, it is only returning the first word..

Can any one please tell me how to do this?

Comment: You could read the file yourself, messy, but it would over come the issue with how Properties translates each line

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to read the properties file using file reader and splitting with regex.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can escape the spaces in your properties file, but I think it will start to look pretty ugly.

```
username=a
password=b
Parent\ file\ name=c
Child\ file\ name=d
```

You might be better of writing your own implementation with [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) or [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) or whatever your heart desires to avoid any future bugs and/or headaches.

Comment: the java.util.Properties.load() method has a few built in separators, including =, space, :   If you want to use any of these in a property name, you need to escape it with a \ character.  It's unfortunate that the javadocs don't really mention this, but the documentation in apache commons-config while not explicity for this method does apply (at least in terms of property/value delimiter) http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfiguration.html

Comment: One semi random addition: when using properties files take great care to avoid unintended whitespace at the end of the property! Although the whitespace surrounding the '=' is ignored, the whitespace at the end isn't and can cause hair-pulling bugs.

Answer (score 7):

In `Java.util.Properties` , `=`, `:`, or white space character are key/value delimiter when load from property file.

Below are detailed Javadoc of its `public void load(Reader reader)`

> The key contains all of the characters in the line starting with the first non-white space character and up to, but not including, the first unescaped `=`, `:`, or white space character other than a line terminator. All of these key termination characters may be included in the key by escaping them with a preceding backslash character. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
public class PropHelper {
    final static String PROPERTY_FILEPATH = "blah/blah.properties";

    static String getPropertyWithSpaces(String property, String delimiter) {
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(PROPERTY_FILEPATH);
            Properties propertiesObj = new Properties();
            propertiesObj.load(reader);
            return propertiesObj.getProperty(property).replaceAll(delimiter, "");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("FATAL ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Somewhere in **.properties** file:

```
settings = ` ⚙ Settings `
```

This is how I call it:

```
System.out.println("|" + PropHelper.getPropertyWithSpaces("settings", "`") + "|");
```

This method works with leading, internal and trailing spaces.
Enjoy!

Answer (score -4):

It seems to be working fine for me; here is my code:

```
   Properties prop = new Properties();
   prop.setProperty("test1", "val1");
   prop.setProperty("test number 2", "val number 2");
   prop.setProperty("test 3", "val3");
   prop.setProperty("test #4", "val #4");
   for(Enumeration<String> en = (Enumeration<String>) prop.propertyNames();en.hasMoreElements();){
       String key = (String)en.nextElement();
       System.out.println("'" + key + "'='" + prop.getProperty(key) + "'");
   }
```

And the output:

```
'test 3'='val3'
'test number 2'='val number 2'
'test1'='val1'
'test #4'='val #4'
```

You can compare that to yours as far as setting it goes, as our displaying seems to be the same. If you don't see anything, add your full code, and I'll take a look

Comment: But you're not reading the properties from a Properties File which is where the OP is having problems.