# Regular expression to read sentence only until '=' but not including

Tags: java, regex, properties

I am trying to read the properties file with keys including spaces.

For ex:

```
Parent File name = 'Mother.Older'
Child File name = 'Daughter.Younger'
```

I tried the regular expression `^.*=` and it successfully reads the keys but it also reading the `=` sign.

Is there any better regular expression which reads the keys only until the `=` sign.

[Link for my original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838674/how-to-read-property-name-with-spaces-in-java)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `^[^=]*`. The `^` inside the `[]` means not, so `[^=]` matches any character except `=`.

Comment: But consider using java's built in properties reading tools. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html.

Comment: @riri see the linked question for why the OP wants to do it himself.

Comment: @Woody, Excellent..It was so easy..i was reading look behind, look ahead and all that stuff..Thanks again.